# How can I use conditional formatting to highlight cells that don't reference a cell on another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a workbook that contains two sheets, **fruits** and **images**.  The **images** sheet has a *Fruit Reference* column to specify which *Fruit ID* on the **fruits** sheet is shown in the image.

**fruits** sheet:

[image: fruits sheet]

**images** sheet:

[image: images sheet]

Now, I want to apply conditional formatting to the *Fruit ID* column and highlight in red all fruit IDs that do not have a matching value in the *Fruit Reference* column of the **images** sheet.

In this example, that means I want to highlight in red *fruit-banana*.

I have tried to use conditional formatting for this (Rule option: Use a formula to determine which cells to format), but I'm not very familiar with Excel, and I can't figure out how to write a formula that says, "for the current cell, return false if it the value doesn't match any of the values in the **Fruit Reference** column.)

Comment: Use `Countif`, if the result is `0` then you know a given value is not in the Images sheet

Comment: SUMPRODUT FUNCTION CAN ALSO HELP YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hint by @cybernetic.nomad to use `COUNTIF`, I configured it as follows:

- On the fruits sheet, open Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules.
- New Rule
- Use a formula to determine which cells to format
- `=IF(COUNTIF(images!$B:$B, $B2) < 1, 1, 0)`. The `IF` is necessary because we need to invert the result of COUNTIF (true if there are no results, false if there are any results).
- Set formatting to fill with red.